# Why don't Separators show up in my Chrome Extension context menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just noticed separators are gone from my Extension's context menu. Following code used to work...

Here's the snippet that should create a separator and then a set of contextmenu choices defined by an array.

No errors are thrown and this section of code does run. If I introduce a typo into the separator code ("type": 'sepERATOR') I **DO** get an error.

Anyone else noticed problems with separators? Running Chrome 71. Am I missing something stupid (on my part)? Thank you!

```
  console.log('Add divider before Faves-----------------------');
  //  Add divider before Faves
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "type": 'separator',
    "contexts": ["page", "selection", "editable"]
  });

  $.each(arrTempFave, function(f, fave){
      chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": fave.faveLabel,
        "id": fave.id,
        "contexts": ["page", "selection", "editable"],
      });
  });
```

Comment: https://crbug.com/904220 fixed in Chrome 72.

Comment: Argggh! Thank you @wOxxOm!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
i=1;
contexts = [ "all" ] ;
chrome.contextMenus.create({id: "s"+(i++) ,type:"separator","contexts":contexts  });
chrome.contextMenus.create({id: "s"+(i++) ,type:"separator","contexts":contexts  });
chrome.contextMenus.create({id: "s"+(i++) ,type:"separator","contexts":contexts  });
```